# How can I get values from certain cells to copy to different spreadsheet onEdit of one cell, when using simple triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to coding and have what for many is a simple problem.
I want to transfer data from 2 cells in form spreadsheet to last row in different spreadsheet. I can get this to work if transferring to different tab within sheet but not to different sheet. What I have is below and is mostly editing of stuff I have found here:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C27') {

  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Sheet1
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WIp-tBahgNJ_BTa0up89J5KMGoJOJyCfX6K6_leKFPM/edit#gid=1733591209");

  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Archive");


  var values = [[formSS.getRange("C6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C23").getValue()]];


  target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
```

Comment: I've also used for last linebut haven't been successful with this either:   target_sheet.getRange(target_sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues(values);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a simple trigger: onEdit(e).

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) about simple triggers:

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
> simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
> authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
> Language service, which is anonymous.

You need user permission to open another spreadsheet using a URL. That's why it won't work.

To get it done, you need to use an installed trigger instead.
Rename your function and click [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) for step-by-step instructions on how to set it up.